# how to create a table which can store pdf,doc file and how to insert the file

Tags: asp.net, sql

For my application I need to get the resume of user from a .net application and the resume need to be viewed only by the admin . I know how to get the resume in .net application .  But I do no how to store the resume (i.e) .pdf or .doc in SQL SERVER

Comment: you can save everything in binary in blob there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look Out this

Save Different types of files into SQL Server Database using File Uploader Control

http://ajaxuploader.com/h/Save-Files-to-Database-using-FileUpload-Control.htm